# How to get Position of my clicked Object(XNA)

Tags: c#, debugging, xna, game-engine, monogame

First of all we are in XNA/Monogame :)

Hey guys,
I have classes like DebugWindow, GameObject, Player(Child from GO),DebugItemSlot

and my question is how to get the position of the gameobject that I just clicked? I already got a click Event so I just need to get the data from the GO I just clicked. Because later on I want to Edit things with my DebugWindow. Hope you understand me and we can come together. If you wish I can add code later that's 
not the problem.

Comment: Your GameObjects should contain a Vector2D position. If your window receives a click you check for a "collision".

E.g your GameObject contains a rectangle property. After a click you retrieve the current mouse position and check if they intersect. new Rectangle(Mouse.X, Mouse.Y, 2, 2).Intersects(GO.Rectangle); If the result is true, you know which GO is overlapping the cursor.

Comment: Yeah I have a Rectangle that's called bounds already and I'm already checking if i clicked an Object but how can I know which Object it is and how to pass the data to my DebugWindow class? Code examples would be good